# How to explain long duration of study caused by "slacking off"?

Tags: interviewing, student

My 5 year study of mechanical engineering ultimately ended up taking almost 9 years. While I had some technically relevant holiday jobs during that time, I don't have a good explanation why it took me almost double the time expected. No relevant part-time jobs that go year-round, no fancy side projects, no voluntary NGO work... the truth, of course, is that I just **love** drifting through life, slacking off and doing nothing of any productive value.

Now if some interviewer person were to ask me about my long duration of study, how could I phrase things to not immediately be marked as a total deadbeat?